# How to display progress bar till data is loaded in Chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I am using JQuery Chosen (ASP.NET 4.0) to display the data from database in select box.

The data to load is taking some time and the page becomes unresponsive. I would like to display a loading message till then

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used JQuery Chosen, but I would imagine you could show/hide a div by using the jquery global ajax event handlers.

https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/